# Decomposition of finite abelian groups in primecomponents

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

The definition of a **primecomponent** of an abelian group $G$ for a prime $p$ is the following:
$$
G_p:\{a\in G: \text{ord} (a) = p^{l(a)} \}<G
$$

Now the **theorem about the decomposition of finite abelian groups** in primecomponents says that with $G$ abelian finite group and ord$(G)=p_1^{k_1}\cdot...\cdot p_1^{k_r}$ with pairwise different $p_1,...,p_r$ then $$G=G_{p_1}\times ...\times G_{p_r}$$ is an inner direct product and ord$(G_{p_i})=p_i^{k_i}$ for $i=1,...r$.

I think I just struggle with the notation. All along here I will write $Z(n)=Z_n=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. It is clear to me that from the theorem of the prime decomposition we can group together all the factors of the same prime number, so for example if the prime decomposition has that 
$$
G\cong Z(q_1^{l_1}) \times Z(q_1^{l_2}) \times ... \times Z(q_1^{l_s})
$$
and $p=q_1,...q_n$ and $p\neq q_i$ for $i\in\{n+1,...,s\}$ we could write
$$
G_p=Z(p^{l_1}) \times Z(p^{l_2}) \times ... \times Z(p^{l_n})
$$
and I would see how because $G_p$ are subgroups of an finite abelian group there are normal, $G_{p_1}\cdot...\cdot G_{p_r}=G$ and also disjunct, so it is an inner product. But **what I cannot understand** is how this defined $G_p$ is a subgroup of G. For example
$$
G:= Z(2) \times Z(2^2)\times Z(2^4)\times Z(3)\times Z(3^3)\times Z(5)
$$
One would assume $G_2=Z(2) \times Z(2^2)\times Z(2^4)$, $G_3=Z(3)\times Z(3^3)$ and $G_5=Z(5)$. I just can't understand how $G_2<G$ is a subgroup of G. For example let $(a_1,a_2,a_3) \in Z(2) \times Z(2^2)\times Z(2^4)$. But how is $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ also in the much larger product $Z(2) \times Z(2^2)\times Z(2^4)\times Z(3)\times Z(3^3)\times Z(5)$? Are elements of $G$ not of the form $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But $G_1\times e\le G_1\times G_2$ quite clearly, in general.

Comment: Yes, that's quite clear of course. But then one would get into trouble with the $G_i$ being disjoint for the conclusion of the inner direct product, they have to be normal, their product has to be $G$ and they need to be disjoint right?

Comment: Disjoint?  Well, $G\times e\cap e\times G=(e,e)=e_{G\times G}$.  Consider the Klein four group.  You can cross a group with itself.

Comment: The factors of the product automatically have trivial intersection.

Comment: Yes well... this explains it. Thank you very much. So I have to understand $G_2=Z(2) \times Z(2^2) \times Z(2^4) \times \{e\} \times \{e\} \times \{e\}$ right?

Comment: Bingo.  You are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much.